# Generate values for str.format style template strings from formatted output

Tags: python

This might seem like a wierd requirement, but I am looking for a good implementation to do this.

I have a dict like

```
vals = dict(red='#F00', green='#0F0', blue='#00F')
```

and a string like

```
tpl = '{red}:{green}:{blue}'
```

and the `str.format`ted output

```
output = tpl.format(**vals)
```

All is well till here. However, I now need to do the reverse of this. I have to turn a string like `'#F00:#0F0:#00F'` into a dict of the values that we previously started with. Of course, I could just `split` and `strip` the string and take the values I need, but it will fail in the event the `tpl` string should change.

Any good ideas on how I can do this (If it can even be done, that is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. (And maybe then you'll have two problems.)

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('(#[\da-fA-F]{3})')
>>> l = pattern.findall(output)
['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F']
>>> dict(zip(('red', 'green', 'blue'), l))
{'blue': '#00F', 'green': '#0F0', 'red': '#F00'}
>>>
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple, me likes it :). Also, we do have two problems, the second being *we now need a regex that matches the substitution strings correctly* ;)

Comment: You want something like `parse('{red}:{green}:{blue}', '#F00:#0F0:#00F')` that returns `vals`? That's more complicated, why don't you write out a solution and post it here, and it can be improved/fixed if required.

Comment: @rm, have been working on it for over a couple hours now. So far, its little more than doctests and a long undo history :)

Comment: But I am starting to doubt the possibility of such a thing now.

Comment: Yep, this is the best way we have :)